# Schedule a task to wake and sleep Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make a my laptop wake from sleep and then go back to sleep after a few moments.

To wake the PC I scheduled a cmd.exe with the argument `/c exit` and it works fine.

To sleep I use a bat file with the following lines:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 15 > nul 
Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep
```

The ping is to both a 15 second delay.

Both of these work individually but when combined it doesn't work correctly.
When the PC is asleep I see it wake, although the screen remains off and then after the 15 second delay it doesn't go back to sleep.

What am I doing wrong if I want to take a sleeping PC, wake it for 15 seconds and then go back to sleep?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you combining in a single BAT file. I suggest create 2 BAT Files one each for stating cmd.exe and next for ping and sleep commands. Then in third BAT file put START command followed by /WAIT to trigget each BAT file one after another. See if this helps. To wake the monitor you can use freeware called NirCMD http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: The wake function and the sleep function are different from entries but I will try your way and get back to you